# Can you create an object when destructuring function arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Basically I'm trying to see if I can do this:

```
var state = {
  lastMessage: {
    owner: 'lastMessageOwnerID'
  },
  owner: 'currentMessageOwnerID'
}

function isSameMessageOwner ({ lastMessage, owner: currentMessage: { owner } }) {
  return lastMessage.owner === currentMessage.owner
}

var isSameOwner = isSameMessageOwner(state)
```

I don't think you can, but just checking :)

Comment: That syntax can't be right.

Comment: I don't understand. What object are you trying to create?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm trying to create the `currentMessage` object so that inside the function I can use `currentMessage.owner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you create an object when destructuring function arguments?

No. Destructuring only allows you to assign existing values to variables. It doesn't allow you to *create* new values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? I'm on the fence about destructuring deeply nested objects, I think it's hard to read, but maybe it will get better with time.

```js
var state = {
  lastMessage: {
    owner: 'lastMessageOwnerID'
  },
  owner: 'currentMessageOwnerID'
}

function isSameMessageOwner ({
  lastMessage: { owner: lastMessage },
  owner: currentMessage
}) {
  return lastMessage === currentMessage
}

var isSameOwner = isSameMessageOwner(state)

console.log(isSameOwner)
```